# Converting oracle tables values into PDF or TXT

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Source is Oracle table, target can be TXT or PDF, that will have a specific format. I know I will need Transaction control transformation, but not sure how I will write in specific location of a TXT files.

SOURCE:

```
ID NAME SAL LOC
01 AA 200 AZ
02 BB 250 AZ
03 CC 300 AZ
```

TARGET:

PDF or TXT 1

```
ID:01
NAME: AA
SAL: 200
LOC: AZ
```

PDF or TXT 2

```
ID:02
NAME: BB
SAL: 250
LOC: AZ
```

PDF or TXT 3

```
ID:03
NAME: CC
SAL: 300
LOC: AZ
```

Comment: I see two things here: you are splitting your data into files based on ID, and you are pivoting columns to rows. Which of these two is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could just use a transaction control. Define the condition as TC_COMMIT_AFTER, since every row will create a new file. To format the data in a text file you can either use a normalizer or just use an expression to concatenate the values with newline characters.

Note that you cannot create a PDF directly from Informatica PowerCenter. You will have to work with text files only.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use normalizer to achieve the transpose of data
2. Issue a TC_commit_after for each record to create a new file
3. take the desired field into the target table file name field. You need to enable this field inside the target metadata before connecting. If you take id into this field, then files will be named 01,02 and 03 and so on. If you need a custom name, take values into expression and then feed into this field.